# How do you track each setInterval cycle?

Tags: javascript

```
function count(){
    //user input stored in the last index of the array each cycle
    array[lastindex]=userinput;
    setInterval(count,5000);
}
```

Like me sample codes above, I am populating the array by storing the user inputs.However, I want to add one more case to this, which is if the users dont type in anything within 5 seconds, I am still able to store a "mark" that indicates that. in other words, how can I detect this automatically before the next cycle? Thank you

Comment: didnt get your question completely but clearInterval() might help

Comment: can you explain what problem are you solving with this?

Comment: array[lastindex]=userinput can easily be substituted with array.push(userinput), unless your array is a cyclic buffer, and not continuously growing.

Comment: Also, using setInterval to invoke the function already being executed is going to eventually thrash, you either need to use setTimeout, or use setInterval outside of the function being called.  Oh +1 to jimy's suggestion too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine it like this - store a variable that indicates that user is typing now. Add an event, for example, keyup to the input where user types in, that after 5 sec of idleing changes that varianble.

```
var
   userTyping = false,
   typingId;


$("input").keyup(function(){
   userTyping = true;
   window.clearInterval(typingId);
   typingId = window.setTimeout(function(){userTyping = false;}, 5000);
});
```

And then the check:

```
function count(){
//user input stored in the last index of the array each cycle
if(!userTyping){
  array[lastindex]=userinput;
}
setTimeout(count,5000);
}
```

Note that you should use setTimeout if within the function, not the setInterval each time you call - that would end up badly...

Answer (score 0):

So first question is does no new input means `userInputOld === userInput` or `userInput === ""`? I'll guess no, because than it would be trivial to check.

You must make a variable that will mark whether there was input or not. Let's presume keyboard input:

```
var hasInput = false;
$("input").keyup(function(){hasInput = true;})
```

Then you can check it in your code

```
function count(){
    //user input stored in the last index of the array each cycle
    if (hasInput) {
        array[lastindex]=userinput;
    } else {
        aray[lastindex]=null;
    }
    setInterval(count,5000);
}
```

Anyway I would like to ask what exactly are you doing, because it looks like you can probably do it better altogether.